# Return value from cond

Tags: if-statement, scheme

I'm trying to interpret a list of keywords and integers to obtain an expression. If "input" is, say '(add 5 5), the incoming list would contain 3 pieces -> add 5 5

```
 (define (evaluate input)
   (if (integer? input)
       input
       (cond ((integer? (car input))
              (car input))
             ((equal? (car input) "add")
              (+ (evaluate (cdr input)) 
                 (evaluate (cddr input))))
~more~
```

I'm using the 'if' because cond doesn't like just returning a value. My questions are: Does equal? actually compare strings properly and should the (+ evaluate (...) evaluate(...)) actually return 10 in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line,

```
 (+ (evaluate (cdr input)) (evaluate (cddr input))))
```

has to be

```
(+ (evaluate (cadr input)) (evaluate (caddr input))))
```

Because in the if-comparison, it has to return directly the number. But of course, instead you can also use cond, you dont have to use a other comparison methode.

To compare strings, you can use best string=? function.

[More info:](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string~3d~3f%29%29)

Comment: Apparently it isn't a string? It came back with: string=?: contract violation
  expected: string?
  given: 'add
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
   "add"

Comment: The string=? isn't needed, just changing the cdr and cddr in evaluate has it returning 10 now.

Comment: Be careful: symbols and strings are not the same thing. `'add` is not the same thing as `"add"`.

Answer (score 1):

`add` is actually a Scheme symbol, not a string, so you can just use `eq?`:

```
(define (evaluate input)
  (cond
    [(integer? input)
      input]
    [(integer? (car input))
      (car input)]
    [(eq? 'add (car input))
      (+ (evaluate (cadr input) (caddr input)))]))
```

BTW, it looks like what you're really trying to do is "destructure" the input when it matches a pattern: that is, extract stuff that's stored inside the input. There's a nice little macro by Oleg Kiselyov called `pmatch` that does this for you. Download it from http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c311/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=pmatch.scm . Then you can write the following, which handles all that `cdr`/`cadr`/`caddr`/etc. stuff automatically, and supports any number of arguments to `add`, and doesn't need the case where an integer is enclosed alone in parentheses:

```
(define (evaluate input)
  (pmatch input
    [,n (guard (integer? n))
      n]
    [(add . ,operands)
      (apply + (map evaluate operands))]))
```

`pmatch` expects a series of clauses, like `cond`, except the first expression in the clause is a pattern, which can contain variables. The variables are indicated by preceding them with a comma (just as in a backquote expression). Any symbols in a pattern that aren't preceded by a comma must match literally. When `pmatch` finds a matching pattern, it binds the variables to the parts of the input that are in the corresponding parts of the input. `n` and `operands` are variables in the patterns above.

You can also stick a `guard` clause after a pattern if you want to require a condition beyond just matching the pattern, like checking if the extracted variable is an integer.

Comment: I appreciate the extra info, but I am unfortunately limited to a small number of built-in functions for this project :(